# PieChart skipping Callout labels

Tags: bugs, labeling, charts

I have a `PieChart` that needs a formatted label. Since some of the sectors are small I want to use `Callout` for those but keep the label for the others.

This concept works for basic data.

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1., "b" -> 2., "c" -> 5., "d" -> 3.|>;
PieChart[If[# < 2, Callout, Labeled][#, NumberForm[#, {2, 1}]] & /@ assoc]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when evaluated on some other `Association`s the PieChart gives a `FindMinimum` error and does not produce the expected result.  None of the Callouts appear.

```
assoc2 = <|"a" -> 20.1230, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 0, "d" -> 0, 
   "e" -> 18.6519, "f" -> 32.9057, "g" -> 18.2365, "h" -> 1.2884, 
   "i" -> 5.9057, "j" -> 2.8403, "k" -> 0, "l" -> 0, "m" -> 0, 
   "n" -> 1.8480, "o" -> 0|>;
PieChart[If[# < 2, Callout, Labeled][#, NumberForm[#, {2, 1}]] & /@ assoc2]
```

> FindMinimum::eqineq: Constraints in {False} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug? Any ideas how to work around this?
version 11.1.0 on Win 7 Ent

---

CASE: **3883154**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty is that you have multiple zeroes right next to each other in the data set. This is causing difficulty with the positioning algorithm which uses `FindMinimum`. To some extent, this is pathological data, but `Callout` should not completely collapse under this condition:

[image]

The workaround would be to separate the zero data, or to coalesce them together.

Comment: I don't think I want to remove them as there are many of these datasets that are returned from the process and there is a list of colours that must be the same across all of the plots.  However with your info I can swap out the `If` statement for `Which[# > 2, Labeled, # > 0, Callout, True, #1 &]` which avoids wrapping the zeros.  +1 for now.